# Is it possible to migrate mysql tables from utf8 to utf8mb4 solely by modifying the dumped .sql file?

Tags: utf-8, mysql, utf8mb4

Suppose there are 2 mysql databases - `src_db` has `utf8` encoding and has several existing tables, `dst_db` has `utf8mb4` encoding and is newly created.  Will the following steps succeed in migrating those `utf8` tables in `src_db` to `utf8mb4` tables in `dst_db`?

First, dump from `src_db`.

```
mysqldump src_db -uxxx -pyyy > tbls.sql
```

Then search and replace all occurrences of `utf8` with `utf8mb4` in the sql file.

```
sed -i 's/DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci/DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci/g' tbls.sql
sed -i 's/COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci/COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci/g' tbls.sql
sed -i 's/character_set_client = utf8/character_set_client = utf8mb4/g' tbls.sql
sed -i 's/SET NAMES utf8/SET NAMES utf8mb4/g' tbls.sql
```

Then, manually modify any index on `varchar` columns to index only a prefix of the column.  See below as an example.  The only modification is to add `(191)` in the index definition.

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `col` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_tbl_on_col` (`col`(191)),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Finally, import the sql file into `dst_db`.

```
mysql dst_db -uxxx -pyyy < tbls.sql
```

Will all the tables imported into `dst_db` be valid `utf8mb4` tables?

Comment: The best way is to test it; but yes, this should do just fine.

Comment: I agree that it should work.  If possible change `varchar(255)` to `191` instead of using a "prefix" index.  The latter has some issues.

Comment: @RickJames What is the exact issue you're referring to?

Comment: Indexing is limited to 767 bytes, which works fine for `VARCHAR(255) utf8`: 2(length) + 3(utf8 size) * 255 <= 767.  But, for utf8mb4, the max is `VARCHAR(191)`: 2 + 4 * 191 <= 767.

Comment: "Prefix indexing" has a number of failings; it is better to avoid them whenever possible.  By changing the `VARCHAR` to 191 (if possible), then you can avoid prefixing and simply do `INDEX(col)`.